# how to call xml soap api of globus tour

Tags: php, xml, web-services, api, soap

i want to implement the tour API of globus tour :-    "http://webapi.globusandcosmos.com/gvitawapi.asmx?op=GetAllAvailableMediaToursXML"
i am using following code to run xml
    $xml= '
      
      
        
         Globus
       
      
       '; 
      $url='http://localhost/api/api.php';

```
   $ch= curl_init('http://localhost/api/api.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml);
    $result= @curl_exec($ch); print_r($result); die;
    if($result=== false) {
    echo "Error performing request";
    }else{
    $xml_doc= simplexml_load_string($result);

    echo 'Status is ',$xml_doc->status,'<br/>';
    if($xml_doc->status =='SUCCESS') {
     echo 'Data is ',$xml_doc->data,'<br/>';
   }else{
    echo 'Error is ',$xml_doc->errormessage,'<br/>';
   }
  }
```

but it keeps loading the page. please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

you must close the curl connection after execute `curl_close($ch);`
here at your line

```
$result= @curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch); print_r($result); die;
```